# Java Script round function upto 1 decimal point

Tags: javascript, math

```
<script>

var c28 = 15;
var c10 = 3;
var c12 = Math.round((((c28-c10)/9)+parseFloat(c10)),1);
alert(c12);
</script>
```

Before the round, output was **4.3333333**.
I want output as **4.3** after round.
but it is showing **4** only. Decimal part is not showing. Please help.

Comment: multiply by 10 ....round...divide by 10

Comment: `Math.round` doesn't take a precision parameter. May be you indeed want `x.toFixed(1)` that given a number `x` will display its approximation to the specified number of decimals.

Comment: I think you will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary), just substitute "1" for "2" in all the solutions.